# SELECT INTO variable not working in PL\SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Not sure why this isn't working, when the base query (the commented out line) does return a value when I pass in the same id - when executed as a straight query outside the function.

Maybe I need to use execute immediate, but not sure why this is returning a "no data" error.  I got it working with execute immediate, but interested to know what the issue is with the syntax below.

```
create or replace FUNCTION "FN_GET_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS" (
TEMPLATE_USED_ID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  
  v_out VARCHAR2(100);
 
  
BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line(TEMPLATE_USED_ID); 
   
    
    SELECT i_chronicle_id INTO v_out from TABLE_A where R_OBJECT_ID =  TEMPLATE_USED_ID;


    -- // this works // SELECT i_chronicle_id INTO v_out from TABLE_A where R_OBJECT_ID = 'ID_99';

    dbms_output.put_line(v_out); 

    return v_out;
    
    
    
    end;
```

So this returns a count of 1:

```
select count(*) from TABLE_A WHERE R_OBJECT_ID = 'ID_99';
```

But this returns a null value, function defined as above:

```
select FN_GET_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS('ID_99') from dual;
```

This works fine:

```
create or replace FUNCTION "FN_GET_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS" (
TEMPLATE_USED_ID IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  
  v_out VARCHAR2(100);
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  
BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line(TEMPLATE_USED_ID); 
    sql_stmt := 'SELECT i_chronicle_id from TABLE_A where R_OBJECT_ID = :a';
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt into v_out using TEMPLATE_USED_ID;
       
    dbms_output.put_line(v_out); 

    return v_out;
    
    
    
    end;
```

Seems it only doesnt work against this production table.  If I recreate a dummy table and a function against the dummy table it works.

```
CREATE TABLE "ANALYTICS"."TEST_CSP_FUNCTION" 
   (    "R_OBJECT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "I_CHRONICLE_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
) 
   

INSERT INTO TEST_CSP_FUNCTION
(R_OBJECT_ID, I_CHRONICLE_ID)
VALUES
('ID_100', 'Doc A');

INSERT INTO TEST_CSP_FUNCTION
(R_OBJECT_ID, I_CHRONICLE_ID)
VALUES
('ID_101', 'Doc B');

INSERT INTO TEST_CSP_FUNCTION
(R_OBJECT_ID, I_CHRONICLE_ID)
VALUES
('ID_102', 'Doc C');



INSERT INTO TEST_CSP_FUNCTION
(R_OBJECT_ID, I_CHRONICLE_ID)
VALUES
('ID_103', 'Doc D');






create or replace FUNCTION "FN_GET_TEST_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS" (
TEMPLATE_USED_ID IN NVARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  
  v_out VARCHAR2(100);

  
BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line(TEMPLATE_USED_ID); 
    
    SELECT I_CHRONICLE_ID INTO v_out FROM TEST_CSP_FUNCTION WHERE R_OBJECT_ID = TEMPLATE_USED_ID;
    
   
    dbms_output.put_line(v_out); 

    return v_out;
end;
    
    
select FN_GET_TEST_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS(N'ID_103') from dual;
```

returns:

> Doc D

Comment: Is there any chance `template_used_id` is a column in the table in addition to being the name of your variable (this is why posting a reproducible test case, as @Littlefoot requested is helpful)?

Comment: no, template_used_id is just a variable name, no match to table or column names.

Comment: If it works with your dummy table and not with you real table then how are they different? And are you sure the dynamic version works as shown? I thought your real table just had the ID column defined as CHAR rather than VARCHAR2 - [that shows the behaviour you describe](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2c45dfaf078b1c73ba02d0c6242b18be) for the standalone query and static function call, but the dynamic version also gets null (via no-data-found). (Whereas both return data [with VARCHAR2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6e0ad7a3ae996ab82f076d6981c0fe7a).)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I see Char doesn’t work and varchar2 does.  I need to check the types.  Not sure why execute immediate works if the other one doesn’t, dealing with the same types.

Comment: I notice you use NVARCHAR in the test example. Could be some weird multibyte character issue. I'd do a select DUMP(R_OBJECT_ID) just to see what the actual bytes are

Comment: You wrote: "-- // this works // ... where R_OBJECT_ID = '**id_99**'". And then: "So this returns a count of 1: WHERE R_OBJECT_ID = '**ID_99**';" This sounds contradictory especially when you cannot provide reproducible setup. What is the value of `NLS_SORT` and what are values of `select dump(R_OBJECT_ID) ... where <condition that works>` and `select dump(<value of TEMPLATE_USED_ID which doesn't work>) from dual`?

Comment: Hi,  I am running the query against production data I cannot share, so I write the real query, test it and code it, then after pasting into SO, I adjust the code manually to remove real stuff.  It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It works if row with appropriate ID exists in the table.

Demo:

```
SQL> select * From table_a;

R_OBJ I_CHRONICLE_ID
----- --------------
id_99            100
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function fn_get_csp_template_details
  2    (template_used_id in varchar2 default null)
  3  return varchar2 as
  4    v_out varchar2(100);
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_line(template_used_id);
  7    select i_chronicle_id
  8      into v_out
  9      from table_a
 10      where r_object_id = template_used_id;
 11    dbms_output.put_line(v_out);
 12    return v_out;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select fn_get_csp_template_details('id_99') as result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100

id_99
100
SQL>
```

If ID doesn't exist, it'll return `NULL` (if called from `SELECT` statement, as in my example):

```
SQL> select fn_get_csp_template_details('ABC') as result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL>
```

It'll return an exception if called elsewhere:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    l_result := fn_get_csp_template_Details('ABC');
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.FN_GET_CSP_TEMPLATE_DETAILS", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 4


SQL>
```

---

That's how it goes. So, what did you do to make it NOT work as expected?

Comment: it doesnt work, it returns a "no data" error ORA-1403, the ID does exist, as explained in original post.  Execute immediate "into" worked.  Are you saying the syntax is fine as long as the ID exists.

Comment: Well, you "explained" it, while I **demonstrated** it (that's a difference). Please, do as I did and prove it. Post table description (CREATE TABLE statement) and INSERT INTO sample data, as well as the way you're calling the function, along with how Oracle responded. As of syntax, yes - it is OK.

Comment: I put the function definition in which was generating No Data, and the SQL statement which runs as a comment, which does return data, so I have checked the ID exists.  All I need to know, as I thought I was going insane, is that the syntax is viable.  So thanks a million.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not a native English speaker, but - which part of "CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO" and the rest of my previous comment did you not understand? I saw the function (it is OK), but - I can't debug the rest of what you're saying if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: I updated the original question, with what I tried.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: I also added what is working, execute immediate

Comment: Almost there! CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, please.

Comment: well if that works, but it doesn't work against my production table, what's the point?

Comment: "What's the point" as "what's the problem", or "why should I post CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data"? If former, I don't know. If latter, because - if you do that - we (the community) would have the same *environment* as you do.

Comment: It is almost midnight here so I'm going offline. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: I did the process, created separate table, 4 inserts, made a modification to the function to read from that dummy table and it works.  Just doesnt work against what I need it to.  At least I know its not the syntax.

Comment: I updated the question with evidence